# Center content area between header and footer

Tags: html, css, templates, center

**QUESTION:** I am trying to get my {{TEXT}} or ".acton" section to remain centered in the body of the page and between the footer and header at all times.

I'm using this template to build out landing pages in a marketing automation software called ACT-ON. So hopefully whatever fix we can put in for the body content to remain centered will take.

Here is my jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/misterizzo/dMu79/

```
    <body>
<div id="bg">
   <img style="display:block;" src="http://cdn-ci53.actonsoftware.com/acton/attachment/8908/f-0015/1/-/-/-/-/Background_Gradient.png">
</div>
<div id="main">
 <div id="header">
  <div id="top-left"><a href="http://medata.com/"><img src="http://cdn-ci53.actonsoftware.com/acton/attachment/8908/f-0019/1/-/-/-/-/Medata%20With%20Sub%20550x131.png" alt="Visit Medata Home Page" class="logo" title="Medata.com" atl="Logo"></a>
  </div>

    <div id="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="http://newsworthy.medata.com/" target="_blank"><span class="button">NewsWorthy</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">Solutions</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">About Us</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">Home</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </div>

<div class="acton">
{{TEXT}}
</div>

<div id="footer">
<ul>
        <li><a href="http://newsworthy.medata.com/" target="_blank"><span class="button">NewsWorthy</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">Solutions</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">About Us</a>
            </span>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#"><span class="button">Home</a>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>



</div>
</body>
```

Hopefully this is my last questions on this template i've been building. 
I sincerely appreciate all the help from everyone so far!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easely use the display : `table,table-row/table-cell` properies along with : `vertical-align:middle;` if your HTML is valid and with the structure needed.

Reset CSS should be loaded in front of your own CSS, it will, as well,  avoid to use !important.

`// comment //` is not a valid comment in CSS, but `/* comment */` is.

http://jsfiddle.net/dMu79/7/

basicly the structure is :

```
<body or wrapper><!-- as heigh/width:100%; and display:table -->
<header> as table-row</header>
<main> as table-cell and height:100% , it will shrink to leave space to header and footer</main>
<footer> as table-row</footer>
</body or wrapper>
```

Comment: Thank you for this, this seems to work the best so far!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that may work for you:

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/dMu79/3/)**

CSS:

```
.acton {
    width: 900px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    height: auto;
    top: 106px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're HTML is broken in places and is missing a closing `div`. I've fixed it in this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DAC84/dMu79/4/)** and the updated code is below:

```
 <div id="header">
      <div id="top-left">
           <a href="http://medata.com/"><img src="http://cdn-ci53.actonsoftware.com/acton/attachment/8908/f-0019/1/-/-/-/-/Medata%20With%20Sub%20550x131.png" alt="Visit Medata Home Page" class="logo" title="Medata.com" atl="Logo"></a>
       </div>

      <div id="nav">
           <ul>
                <li>
                     <a href="http://newsworthy.medata.com/" target="_blank"><span class="button">NewsWorthy</span></a>
                </li>
                <!-- the closing span's were after the closing A -->
                ...
           </ul>
      </div>
 </div> <!-- this div was missing -->
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting a margin top in the .action section.

Also I removed the position-right and position-left

Notice that the margin-top is set to 40%. This is because it takes in to account the nav and the footer. You can play with the margin depending on the other content that is added above it or below it.

working jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/dMu79/9/

```
.acton {
    width: 900px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 40%;
    text-align: center;
}
```